# Activate onclick=showpage() using Python's mechanize

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm emulating a browser using python's mechanize module, and I'm having a bit of trouble using links that don't actually link to another url, but just activate a javascript function that requests some php action. Here is the link I want to use, part of an unordered list in a navigation bar menu:

```
                            <a href="#" onclick="showpage('dataTitle.php');"><i class="clip-phone-3"></i>
                                <span class="title">dataTitle</span>
                                <span class="selected"></span>
                            </a>
```

I've been trying things like this:

```
resp = br.click_link(text = "Dumps")
req = br.open(resp)
print req.read()
```

But I do not see the data table that I should*, just the html data that was on the page to begin with, before clicking the link.

*What I expect to see is the same thing that I see when I click the link using a mouse and an actual browser. I'm concerned that the mechanize click_link() function follows the href address, which is a dummy placeholder here, and does not activate the onclick function.

Is it possible to activate this kind of thing using mechanize, or do I have to scrap the work done thus far and move to something like phantomjs?

Comment: Mechanize doesn't do JavaScript, so in order to make this work like it does in a regular Browser, you'd indeed have to use something like PhantomJS or Selenium. But depending on how complex the involved JS is (particularly the `showpage()` function), you might be able to emulate parts of the behavior. Use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) or Chrome's developer tools to monitor network requests, and see what request is being sent to `dataTitle.php`. Then you might be able to emulate that request from your code.

Comment: Thanks @LukasGraf, that was really helpful. I'm using the second method you suggested, in attempts to preserve the work done so far. Studying the post requests being made and replicating them using mechanize and urllib.